# Where does the variable holding an element with an id get stored?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This question ( [Element accessible with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12663981/1026459) ) points out that if an element has an id then you can access it by variable name based on that id. It intrigued me, as I had seen this variable available when developing using Visual Studio 2010. I did some testing out of curiosity and it turns out that `document.getElementById()` was still faster than using the variable name. So, I began trying to look through the window, figuring it must be in `window["idName"]`, in debug, and with `console.log(window)` and could not find where the variable was actually stored.

When an element is defined in html with `<div id="foo">` it is available in javascript with the variable `foo` (I am not suggesting to use this, it is bad practice). Where is that variable stored?

Comment: Please do not make it a practice to access elements as global variables. It's a hideous IE invention, and is non-standard. Exactly where the identifier is located is up to the implementation, since there's no standard to define this.

Comment: @user1689607 - I agree that it is bad practice (even noted here in the question and in the linked one not to use it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is non-standard behavior. Where (and if) it is stored is up to the implementation.

---

Using `Firefox 15` on Linux, I had to go 2 prototype objects deep to find the actual object. I ran this code on this StackOverflow page, and got a `true` result.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(window)).hasOwnProperty("hlogo");
```

---

In Chrome on Linux, it was one level deep.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(window).hasOwnProperty("hlogo");
```

---

I was actually surprised to see it in Firefox, but since Chrome followed the Microsoft pattern, I guess Firefox must have felt the need to follow suit.

---

If you don't know how deep a prototype chain is, you can run a loop, and add the different objects to an Array, or just work with the objects in the loop.

```
var protos = [],
    obj = window;

while (Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) !== null) {
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    protos.push(obj);
}

alert("The object had " + protos.length + " prototype objects");
```

Comment: And in Chrome, that's `false`, but `Object.getPrototypeOf(window).hasOwnProperty("hlogo")` is `true`.

Comment: @MattBall: Yes, just tested that myself. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user1689607 - Very nice, thank you for showing a repeatable way to view this variable. I tested with Firefox and was able to get the result "two prototype objects deep". Do you think you could expand on why it took two, and what the outer `Object.getPrototypeOf` means here?

Comment: @TravisJ: The `Object.getPrototypeOf` method is a way to retrieve the prototype object of an object. A prototype chain can be longer than just one object, so basically the Firefox code says *"give me the prototype object of the prototype object of the `window` object"*. In other words, the inner one gets the prototype of `window`, and so the outer gets the prototype of the prototype of `window`.

Comment: @TravisJ: I'll update with a loop that will add each prototype object in the prototype chain to an Array. Index `0` will be closest to the original object.

Comment: @user1689607 - Thanks for the extra explanations, I appreciate it. I understand prototypes, but do not yet have a strong grasp of them.