# Functionality of Javascript functions and jquery selectors from within html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this javascript function:

```
function clearDiv(div_id) {
    alert(div_id);
    $(div_id).empty();
}
```

And the following html:

```
<input value="Clear" type="button" onClick="clearDiv(div_to_clear)" />

<div id="div_to_clear">
    <!-- more html -->
</div>
```

Why is it that the above will actually find the javascript div object with id `div_to_clear` and use the `$` selector to access it?

If I had done the input as :

```
<input value="Clear" type="button" onClick="clearDiv('div_to_clear')" />
```

I would need to change my function to

```
function clearDiv(div_id) {
    alert(div_id);
    $('#' + div_id).empty();
}
```

Is there any documentation about this? Are there advantages to using one method or the other?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Are you sure `div_id` isn't being set somewhere else globally?

Comment: @j08691 [I've been able to c.c](http://jsfiddle.net/V6dXN/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE (and Chrome in an effort for compatability) will create properties on the window with names of elements with ids, corresponding to those elements.

In the first example are are passing `window.div_to_clear` which points to your element directly.  In the second, you are passing a string telling jQuery which element to select.

The first one is non-standard behavior so you should not rely on it.

Comment: Because I don't have firefox installed right now, will the first method pass `div_to_clear` as a string to my js function?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No.  An unquoted string is treated like a variable, as previously noted in this answer.

Comment: I actually just tried it in Firefox and it works, which is new to me.  Still, I wouldn't rely on it.  And if it is not quoted, it is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is actually a browser bug (they called it a feature) to access the DOM node by `window.div_to_clear` (the global variable) - and jQuery creates its wrapper around the element. For legacy reasons, it still exists in current browsers, but is deprecated. Your really should use the selector solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is a widely-implemented (although ***`not`*** best practice) method by browsers to automatically place html elements with `id`'s into their correlating variable name. For example:

```
<div id="someId"></div>
```

will end up psuedo creating the variable `someId` which holds that html element.

These questions have similar information on the behavior:

[Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1026459)

[Where does the variable holding an element with an id get stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12680124/1026459)

[Element accessible with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12663981/1026459)

Here is a jsperformance test showing that accessing the id in that manner is slower than using `document.getElementById`: http://jsperf.com/global-id-vs-document-getelementbyid