# javascript and Dom and object initialisation

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)
>   [Element accessible with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663981/element-accessible-with-id)

I tried this code that is not expected to work:

```
<html> 
<head>
<script>
function change() {
    alert("changing !!"+dummy);
    dummy.innerHTML="hello !!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dummy" onclick="change();" > nothing good here !! </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it seems to work fine (ff16, ie8, chrome) while `dummy` is not initialized like it should be via a `document.getElementByID('dummy');` is this a html5 feature or just a edge effect?

Answer (score 1):

Now All browser create global variable for each id present in dom. See [my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663981/element-accessible-with-id)

```
dummy == document.getElemetById('dummy') // true
```

Comment: Shouldn't you vote to close this question as a duplicate of yours then? Seems to be exactly the same question...