# Javascript Quirk: accessing node without getElementByID

Tags: javascript, browser, syntax, w3c, quirks-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)
>   [Element accessible with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663981/element-accessible-with-id)

I didn't realise until recently that you can access a DOM element by it's ID without using document.getElementByID()

```
​<div id="test">
  hi there
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​alert(test.textContent);​ //alerts "hi there"
```

What's weirder is that it is supported in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9+

The only problem I can see is if you overwrite the name ie) `var test=3;` and it would no longer work. But you have that same problem when setting `var test = document.getElementById('test');`

My questions are:

-Why/how does this work... Is the browser accessing it through the window object?

-Is it a bad practice?

-Is it supported by older browsers (IE6)?

Comment: This is a duplicate, hold on while I go find the previous questions.

Comment: @zzzzBov Here's one dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663981/element-accessible-with-id

Comment: Ahhh ok, I couldn't find it amongst the sea of getElementById questions.

Comment: Thanks guys, yep definitely a duplicate, Voted to close.